# Why is Built in JComponent method throwing 'Cannot Find Symbol'?

Tags: java, jcomponent

Everything about this code works fine except getInputMap. I've looked all over and cannot find a reason why it does not. In the program it's saying cannot find symbol. How can that be if it's a built in method of JComponent?

```
package dungeon_adventure;


public class Dungeon_Adventure {
public static Dungeon_Adventure_Display Dungeon_Display;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    game_engine();
}

private static void game_engine() {
    String welcome_text = "Welcome to Dungeon Adventure\nStay a while!\nStay 
    forever!";
    Dungeon_Display = new Dungeon_Adventure_Display();
    Dungeon_Display.getInputMap().put("userInput", "myAction");
    Dungeon_Display.change_image("square_1.jpg");
    Dungeon_Display.add_text(welcome_text);
}

}
```

Comment: "it's saying cannot find symbol"? [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: for the 'getInputMap() portion. Yes it is red underlined with that message.